# i2cdetect -l don't return anything

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, kernel-module, fsb

I need to use the SMBus, but when I run the command `i2cdetect -l` I do not receive anything as output, on Windows it was recognized, I do not see anything about SMBus even doing `lspci`. I installed and inserted the `i2c-dev` module in the startup but I always have the same problem. I'm using Debian 9.5 on a hp proliant dl380 g7.

The output of `cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-*/name` is:
`cat: '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-*/name`: No such file or directory

And I mean the motherboard bus, the one that is used to overclock with the fsb, with: "is recognized on Windows" I mean that using software to see the components I can see the smbus that interests me and see the details, I have searched on the internet about drivers for this motherboard, but I did not find anything about Smbus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to `modprobe i2c-dev`, do `cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-*/name`, and edit your question with the output, so we at least what bus master hardware is currently already recognized. It's entirely possible to have a bus master, but no devices behind it.

Second step is to edit your question with all the details how "the" SMBus (there can be lots of busses, each with different hardware) is recognized under Windows, i.e. what kind of hardware the bus master sits on, which ports it uses, etc.

Third step is to use this data and find the corresponding hardware device under Linux, then check if you have a driver for it.

**Edit**

As long as you don't edit the question which details about *what exactly* you see under windows, I can't be sure, and I'm not familiar with your hardware, but: The motherboard SMBus on Intel-CPU systems is located in the southbridge, uses the `i2c-i801` module on my Intel-based system, and is visible as PCI-card. So (1) edit your question with the output of `lspci -nn`, (2) edit the question with the **details** of what you see under Windows (PCI address, ports, anything that gives a hint how the hardware actually looks like, instead of having us guess).

The "no such file or directory" indicates no module is loaded which actually provides a bus. This could be because your HP has some other hardware, or your Linux kernel has not enabled the module you need, or for a variety of other reasons.

Comment: I have edited the question.